# How to judge a integer type to be a built-in type or not in C++?

Tags: c++

For example, `int` is a built-in type, but `int128` is not.
How to know an integer type is a built-in type or not?

I want the compiler give me the answer, not using the doc, because I have to use the result of whether a type is built-in type in my program.

Comment: note that is_fundamental doesn't include pointers to fundamental types

Comment: `std::is_fundamental_v<std::decay_t<T>>` is false for __int128 and true for int

Comment: @m88: I don't think you need the `decay`. `is_fundamental` already removes cv-qualifications.

Comment: I'm also wondering now _why_ you want to know this. You might want to be more precise about what you expect from a type, e.g. `std::is_trivially_assignable`. That is true for the built-in integer types, but also for some other similar types.

Comment: @MSalters and those traits do not work for _built-in_ `__int128` in GCC at least because there is no guarantee that they should. `__SIZEOF_INT128__` would be 16 and run-time would support the type though, but nothing out of std:: works as ISO doesn't support it

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for `std::is_fundamental<T>::value` or `std::is_arithmetic<T>`.

Comment: `std::is_fundamental_v<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>` could also be good if one wants `int*` to be `true` but `__int128_t*` to be `false`. Without it, both are `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. On a platform with a 128 bit `int`, you may well find that `int128` is a `typedef` for `int`. In which case,

```
std::is_fundamental<int128>::value
```

will be 1.

C++ provides no way of distinguishing a `typedef`.

Comment: I think the question used `int128` as a hypothetical UDT, and the question was how you'd differentiate between built-in types and UDT's.

Comment: @MSalters: Who knows? The important thing for me is that many of the sized types are `typedef`s for fundamental types. And `std::is_fundamental` cannot help you there. The answer might be 0 on one platform, and 1 on another.

Comment: you are adressing the false premise, but that aside it is possible to find out if a type is fundamental or not via the trait

Answer (score 1):

Study the `type_traits` module, apart from `std::is_fundamental` which can tell if a type is fundamental (standard arithmetic types, void or nullptr_t), there is multiple templates for compile-time check of type properties, is it a pointer, is it arithmetic, signed or not, is it reference.

The problem with large integer types is that, if an integer type is supported by compiler, it IS a built-in type. Otherwise its support as an integer type is impossible. But it is NOT guaranteed to be detected as a fundamental. `std::is_trivial<__int128>::value` is true while `std::is_trivially_assignable<__int128,__int128>::value` would return false though, but that's not 100% guarantee that `__int128` is or isn't something emulated, it's up to implementation.

There are libraries which use classes to emulate large integers and those, obviously, can be detected as usually non-trivial classes.
There is no cross-platform  way to detect int128 support but you can rely on fact that it is possible only a) on 64 bit systems, and b) for gcc and clang and some other compilers there is  `__SIZEOF_INT128__` built-in macro.

Some 32bit platform like ARM with NEON support have another 128 bit type albeit it's not used as an integer but as a SIMD type for intrinsic functions, they shouldn't be mixed up with arithmetic type, because alignment requirement might be stricter.

Answer (score -1):

You can find a list of built in types here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/fundamental-types-cpp?view=msvc-160

Comment: I want the compiler give me the answer, not using the doc, because I have to use the       result of whether a type is built-in type in my program. You know, the c++ is evolving fast and wide integer may be added later years.

Comment: The OP doesn't want a list of fundamental types. They want a *meta-programmatic* way of deducing whether an arbitrary type name/alias is, in fact, a native built-in type.